# creating dynamic li elements from json with typeahead - loop error

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js

Using typeahead.js I'm creating li elements from the color item in the json response

Json:

```
"results": [
                {
                    "title": "The Collection",
                    "attribute": "The Collection",
                    "url": "#/test",
                    "image": "images/products/londonretro-caine.jpg",
                    "color": ["brown", "yellow", "grey"]
                },
```

The json has a color key that is sometimes a string, and sometimes an array with several colors

I've looped through the response and created a html dynamically

```
html += '<li></li>'
```

I've added a conditional to check if the item in the json is an array of colors.
If it is an array of colors, I've replaced the html with as many li items, as there are colors in the array

I've tried two methods:
1. One is that I make html equal to the new li elements like so: `html += '<li></li>...'`

2. the other is that I've changed html to an array and I pushed the li elements into it replacing the original html : `html.push('<li></li>')`

With method 1, I get the following result:

I get all the colors in a separate li, 
but I also get an extra first li with the colors like so:

```
<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:brown,yellow,grey' title='brown,yellow,grey'>'brown,yellow,grey'</li>
```

With method 2, I only get the last li with the last color:

```
<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:grey' title='grey'>'grey'</li>
```

I left both solutions in the following code.
Any ideas? Thanks, Ask please if it's unclear..

my typeahead code:

```
suggestion: function (item) {

        var glassesColor = item.color;
        var html = "<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:"+ glassesColor +"' title='"+ glassesColor +"'>'"+ glassesColor +"'</li>";
        _.forEach(item.color, function (k) {
          if (typeof item.color === 'object') {
              html += "<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:"+ k +"' title='"+ k +"'>'"+ k +"'</li>";

              html = [];
              html.push("<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:" + k + "' title='" + k + "'>'" + k + "'</li>");
              var myhtml = html.join(''); 
              html = myhtml;   
          }
        });
        //console.log(html);
        var output = '<div class="search-autocomplete search-glasses">\n';
        output += '<a href="' + item.url + '">';
        output += (item.image ? '<img class="search-autocomplete__image" src="' + item.image + '" alt="' + item.title + '">' : '');
        output += '<span class="search-autocomplete__title">' + item.title + '</span>';
        output += (item.attribute ? '<span class="search-glasses__attribute">' + item.attribute + '</span>' : '');
        output += '<ul class="product-spot__variants">';
        output += html;
        output += '</ul>';
        output += '</a>\n';
        output += '</div>\n';
        return output;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I just created another conditional for the string and put the html equals code there..
otherwise everything was fine

```
if (typeof item.color === 'string') {
          html = "<li class='product-spot__variants-variant' style='background-color:"+ glassesColor +"' title='"+ glassesColor +"'>'"+ glassesColor +"'</li>";
        }
```